# xcode can not be opened because it is in a future format

Tags: ios, xcode

when i try to open the project getting error say can not be opened because it is in a future format. My xcode version is 10.1. is it meaning xcode version is lower one?.if so is there way to open the project? any help will be appreicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the latest Xcode which is version 11.x . You should be able to open the project with that.